# qt.conf with pyside6-deploy? Or: pixel-perfect QGraphicsView ignoring scaling

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, pyside6

My application needs a screen-pixel-perfect display in its `QGraphicsView` regardless of the user's set application scaling. After building one-file with `pyside6-deploy`, I tried to set the scaling method through the file properties (properties -> compatibility -> change high DPI settings -> check scaling override, set to "Application"). This gives me a warning:

```
qt.qpa.window: SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext() failed: The operation completed successfully.

Qt's default DPI awareness context is `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2`. If you know what you are doing, you can overwrite this default using qt.conf (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/highdpi.html#configuring-windows).
```

That provided link says that you can use a `qt.conf` alongside the executable path, i.e. `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + QDir::separator() + "qt.conf"`. Checking this path in the program shows that it's in a temporary folder. How would I be able to bundle a `qt.conf` file in a one-file built program?

Alternative solution: make the `QGraphicsView` specifically ignore scaling.